# How do I rename my keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm working on a custom iOS keyboard, and I've managed to rename my project. But the actual keyboard itself still appears to be the previous name. How do I solve this?

Comment: have u checked the following material https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Comment: Check the following tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the Bundle Display Name (`CFBundleDisplayName`) in your `Info.plist` file *for that extension*.

If your keyboard extension is called "XYZ Keyboard," it would be located in the "Supporting Files" folder in the "XYZ Keyboard" folder.

[image: Info.plist]

You'd change this key:

[image: Bundle Display Name]

If it's not there, you can add it by clicking the plus icon that appears when you hover over "Information Property List" and beginning to type "Bundle Display Name" (it should autocomplete). It may also appear as `CFBundleDisplayName` if you have Raw Keys/Values turned on.

Comment: after doing this, I get the error: error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier. What do I do now?

Comment: @DevonCarlson You must have changed the wrong key. Make sure you're changing Bundle **Display** Name.

Comment: Strange. That is what I did.

Comment: @DevonCarlson Did you change anything else? Changing your bundle display name shouldn't have any effect on the rest of your application because you're merely modifying what appears as the name. Changing your bundle identifier or bundle name, however, would cause problems.

Comment: my apologies! this worked. Now my keyboard is now named "nameiwanted - previous description". How do I fix this?

Comment: @DevonCarlson No problem; I'm glad I could help. Where are you seeing that name?

Answer (score 4):

[image: where to find Bundle dipslay name]

You can change the name of your keyboard by changing the Bundle display name string in the Info.plist in your keyboard extension folder> supporting files>Info.plist>Bundle display name.

In reply to your comment, the keyboards names display as "HostAppName - KeyboardName", make sure the Bundle dislay name in both the host app's Info.plist and the keyboard extension's Info.plist are both what you want (see sidebar in screenshot, both info.plists need updating).

Comment: my keyboard is now named "nameiwanted - previous description". How do I fix this?

Comment: I see. This keyboard is built from sample code that I've changed myself (with the owner's permission of corse). How would I change their bundle identifiers? Sorry if this is a dumb question, i'm brand new to developing.

Comment: @DevonCarlson, leave the bundle identifier the same (at least until you are ready to submit, when you do click on the name of your project (in my screenshot CustomKeyboardSample), go to general tab, and edit bundle identifier there.)

But you probably don't need to edit your bundle identifer now, you need to change the Bundle display name (as you did), for 2 seperate info.plists. Your host app, and the keyboard extension each have their own Info.plist.

Comment: I am reddy to submit. When I click on the bundle identifier it doesn't seem to allow me to actually edit it. What is causing this?

Comment: I was experiencing that problem recently too, it must be a bug in xcode. any way, a workaround is to edit the info.plist property for bundle identifier directly, the same way as you edited the bundle display name.

Comment: This worked for me, but when I add the keyboard, the keyboard name has a subtitle which is part of the old name.  Is there a way to change the subtitle?  thanks